# to write a regular expression in perl for sequence of a's followed by an equal number of b's

Tags: regex, perl

i am asked to write a regular expression in perl for sequence of a's followed by an equal number of b's
regular expressions confuse me too. Please help

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What if the numbers of a's and b's are different? Do you want to match the substring containing equal numbers of both, or reject the whole string? Will the string contain other characters besides a's and b's? Will there be more than one such sequence in a string? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Better give sample output/input

Comment: basically i need the output that contains aaabbb, aaaabbbb, something like this..

Comment: my regular expression should accept this (the output i mentioned in the above comment)

Comment: If I give you an answer, will you be required to explain it to your teacher?

Comment: i don't have to explain it to my teacher. i have to practice .. i have an exam soon.. it is just an example in the exercises

Answer (score 1):

Heres a rough approach.

```
my $str = 'cabccaabbccabb';

while ($str =~ m/(a+)(b+)/g and length $1 == length $2)
{
    print "match: $1, $2\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a not too decrepit version of perl:

```
/(?<ABPAIR>a(?&ABPAIR)?b)/
```

Comment: How about if I want it to fail on unequal lengths, e.g. "aabbb" ?

Comment: @runrig: now you are talking about a match; the request was for a regex.  feel free to wrap it in \b\b or \A\z or non-[ab] lookahead/behinds or whatever you fancy; way too many possibilities and no help from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Should the string "aaabbbb" match because it contains "aaabbb" ? This answer assumes "no". Should the string "only" contain the equal number of a's and b's? Or match the a's and b's within any string? This answer assumes the latter (also, this expression is not considered "regular", but it is perl):

```
$str = "cdaaaabbbbef";

if ( $str =~ /(?>(a+)(?{$a_cnt = length($^N)})(b+))(?{$b_cnt = length($^N)})(??{ ( $a_cnt == $b_cnt ) ? qr(.?) : qr(^.)})/ ) {
  print "Matches! [$1][$2]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with a single regular expression.  You'll need one expression to first count the number of a's, then incorporate that into another expression that matches the same number of b's.

Comment: You can do it with the perl non-regular expression features of `(?{...})` and `(??{...})` possibly with (?>...). But I'm not answering homework questions.